# Attribute Routing with Default Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, asp.net-core-routing

Using attribute based routing I would like to match the following routes:

```
~/
~/Home
~/Home/Index
```

to **HomeController.Index**, and this route:

```
~/Home/Error
```

to **HomeController.Error**. Here is my configuration:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpGet, Route(""), Route("~/")]
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Error() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `Route("[action]")`, `Route("Index")`, and other combinations but still don't get a match for:

```
/Home/Index
```

Comment: FYI - Putting the same content on more than one URL and not using [a canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) is bad for SEO. A better option to use a 301 redirect for `/Home` and `/Home/Index` to redirect all requests and bookmarks to `/`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 good comment, but this is for an internal web application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The empty route `Route("")` combines with the route on controller, use `Route("/")` to override it instead of combining with it:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/")]
    [Route("/[controller]")]
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Error() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `/[action]` on the controller, which makes it a bit easier (no need to override), but then you have to define a route on every action.

I'm assuming that you intentionally want to use attribute routing rather than conventional routing, so the above answer is what you need. However, just in case the assumption is wrong, this can be easily achieved with a simple conventional routing:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Get error: Error: The attribute route 'Home/{action:index}' cannot contain a parameter named '{action}'. Use '[action]' in the route template to insert the value 'Index'.

Comment: You're right. defaults can only be provided on actions in the attribute routing. See my updated answer.

Comment: I was trying to recreate the default conventional routing functionality using attribute routing in a succinct manner without a lot of repetition

Comment: They don't work in the same way, so it is hard to recreate one from another. But my answer allows you to do it without repetition.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Route("[controller]")]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
      [Route("")]     // Matches 'Home'
      [Route("Index")] // Matches 'Home/Index'
      public IActionResult Index(){}

      [Route("Error")] // Matches 'Home/Error'
      public IActionResult Error(){}

 }
```

Comment: Indeed, but I was trying to avoid repeating action name everywhere...argh, seems like should be simpler